# Измерительный метр и рулетка

Tags: синонимы

Слова "метр" и "рулетка" являются синонимами?

Answer (score 3):

**Метр**ом (или "сантиметром") называли измерительную *тканевую* ленту длиной в один или полтора метра, которая при хранении просто сворачивалась в рулон. 
[image: Метр]
Так называли вполне конкретное изделие массового применения (оно было в каждом доме), в СССР у него не было заметно различающихся модификаций (не считая *складного* металлического *метра*). **Рулетка** имеет корпус, из которого вытягивается *жёсткая* (иногда металлическая) мерная лента длиной до нескольких метров. Корпус снабжается средством сворачивания ленты (пружинный механизм или рукоятка). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]В этом смысле **рулетка** - *прибор* или *инструмент*, содержащий измерительную ленту в рулоне, а **метр** - просто лента (реже - складная метровая линейка; в портновском деле и при торговле тканями применяется массивная деревянная нескладная линейка-метр).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть наличие корпуса, механизма сворачивания отличает один предмет от другого?

Comment: Да, рулетка отличается наличием круглого (под рулон) корпуса и тем, что лента жёсткая (выдвигается по прямой).

Comment: Ваше утверждение не есть правда. Корпус у рулетки не всегда круглый, а лента не всегда жесткая. (https://russian.alibaba.com/promotion/promotion_soft-measuring-tape-promotion-list.html)  Не вводите людей в заблуждение.

Comment: Разумеется, случаются рулетки в форме собаки https://www.sima-land.ru/613055/ruletka-5-m-s-dekor-v-forme-sobaki-krasnaya/ и прочие арт-объекты, но это ещё больше _удаляет_ "метр" от статуса "синоним рулетки".

Answer (score 1):

Метр — (2) линейка или **лента** такой длины с делениями на сантиметры, употребляемая для измерения чего-либо (толковый словарь Т. Ф. Ефремовой).

Рулетка — (1) свертываемая в круг металлическая или матерчатая **лента** с делениями, служащая 
для измерения чего-либо (толковый словарь Т. Ф. Ефремовой).

Если предположить, что длина ленты в рулетке равна метру (а такие рулетки, наверно, бывают), то в этом случае понятия являются синонимами.

[МЕТР](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80&all=x) и [РУЛЕТКА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)